# rails - how to render error message from JSON response while using remote true in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have read several posts on SO and several blogs but none of them clearly says how to render an error message on a view when you are using `:remote => true`

I am sure I am not trying to do something not done before.

So I have a form

```
<%= form_for template, url: url, html: {class: 'padding-top-10'}, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'What is the name of the new role?' %>
  <%= f.submit 'CREATE' , class: 'btn-block btn btn-primary'%>
<% end %>
```

All I want is when I submit a form I want to be able to display the error message on screen for the user.

```
def add_job_template
  @template  = JobTemplate.new(job_template_strong_params)
  if @template.save
    render json: { success:  'Information has been saved' }}
  else
    render json: { errors:  @template.errors.full_messages }, status: 422
  end
end
```

Now the question.
How do I display this `success` or `errors` response in my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to handle the response, you could set a value in a message instance variable depending if the record has or not been saved, and then in a js file that responds to your method, to do what you need with this value:

```
def add_job_template
  @template = JobTemplate.new(job_template_strong_params)
  @message  = @template.save ? 'Template saved' : 'Template not saved'
  respond_to :js
end
```

Then in your app/views/templates/add_job_template.js.erb you can show the value of `@message`:

```
console.log('<%= @message %>')
```

If you render a json you have the needed data, but you need something which to say what to do, if you respond with a js format, then it'll look for a js file called as the current method.